# Why won't my image show up?

Tags: html, image

Why doesn't my image show up, it just looks like it doesn't know where the image is. I've checked the source time and time again.

Here is the code:

```
<div id="quinfo">
<p><b>Knowledge Bowl</b></p>
<a href="google.com" target="_blank" >Josh Pletcher&nbsp;<img class="exlink" src="pictures/exlink.pdf" /></a>
<br/>
<a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-N0P5kkkDMu1jtnQ47NcXIDdQk38wKJEEsLP3mjWV04/edit" target="_blank" > Matthew Colvin<a title="Google Drive" >&nbsp;<img class="exlink" src="pictures/exlink.pdf" /></a> 
<br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have nested <a> tags? You also don't close one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pointing to a PDF file. Check the file extension on your image.

```
<img class="exlink" src="pictures/exlink.XYZ" />
```

It should probably be `.jpg`, `.gif` or `.png`.

Comment: It's possible to load a pdf as an image using HTML though. I just tried it and it worked for me, at least on my local machine and browser.

Comment: Thank you. Can't believe I couldn't figure that out. I feel stupid.

Answer (score 0):

As the other person said, you are pointing to a PDF file. Pdf's can have multiple pages, and it can't find what image you are looking for, use image formats ex: .jpg .png .jpeg